# Filling up raster image (ASTER data)

Tags: qgis, raster, void

I have an ASTER DEM with some data gaps. The gaps are not necessarily NULL but rather unusual values. For example, in the image below, the black portion has an altitude in the range of `2000 - 2100 m` while the white space just outside has elevation in range `6000 - 7000 m`. I super imposed the data with google earth image and the second image shows how it looks to G-earth. I've highlighted the parts of interest. [image]   [image]
I measured the length of these blacks, they are less than a kilometer long. The surprising part is that these are the mountain peaks. And there's no way there's gonna be so huge elevation difference.

> What I need to do is fill up these space with relevant data. May be some interpolation techniques be helpful or any other method. Is there a way to fill up such data, in QGIS or may be in R ?

Comment: Have you made a web search to see whether such issues have been fixed in later versions of ASTER dem (e.g. , GDEM2)? Some info here for instance: http://www.digital-geography.com/dem-comparison-srtm-3-vs-aster-gdem-v2/

Comment: @NewAtGis yes, actually the data I am using is the GDEM2 data

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a direct solution for your issue. Before delving into the tricky matter of interpolation and the like, I would search for any other data that may fit your need AND that do not have the 'bugs' you you showed. I have read that some years ago they have released a 30m SRTM DTM that could be fit (resolution-wise) to your needs and (possibly, but I am not 100% sure) might not have those errors. Some info are at the top of this web blog (https://blog23d.wordpress.com/) and data can be freely accessed (after registration) from: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/. Good luck.